# How to retrieve data from XAML TextBlock in code?

Tags: xaml

I've read all the posts and they might be the answer to my question but I don't quite grasp the concept so I'm asking my question in hopes there is a simple answer. I want to retrieve the text from a textblock and feed it to my text to speech code.

The code that needs help is this:

```
if (DataContext == null)
{
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
   `enter code here`         {
                int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
                DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items[index];
                string saythis = "*here is where my question comes in - how do I get the string from the TextBlock in ControlPanel?*"
                Speaker(saythis);
                saythis = "here is where my question comes in - how do I get the string from the TextBlock in ControlPanel2?"
                Speaker(saythis);
            }
        }
    }
    async void Speaker(string words)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync(words);
    }
```

The XAML which came from the Databound model is:

```
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Gr8Oz software" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Heading}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel contains details text. Place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Login}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>

    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Margin="12,123,12,10" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Password}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,10,12,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i actually understand the question right, but if it is just about how to get the text from those specific TextBlocks, why not simply set `x:Name` and then access the appropriate members in code:

```
<Grid ...>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Login}" ..../>
</Grid>
<Grid ...>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Text="{Binding Password}" .../>
</Grid>
```

In code:

```
var firstText = textBlock1.Text;
var secondText = textBlock2.Text;
```

However, as the `Text` properties of the two TextBlocks are bound to some properties `Login` and `Password`, why not directly get the text from these?